# how to set unique validation rules on two columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation

I have a table **city_regionmappings**. Three columns are there:

```
id | regionmasters_id | citymasters_id

1  |    22            |    444
2  |    23            |    445
3  |    24            |    544
```

I am saving rows in above table by two different tables. Now I want to make row unique with combination of two columns **(regionmasters_id and citymasters_id)**. There should not be same rows Like:

```
id | regionmasters_id | citymasters_id

2  |    24            |    544
3  |    24            |    544
```

I tried but not getting my result.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'region_id' => 'required',
            'city_id' => 'required|unique:city_regionmappings,regionmasters_id,NULL,citymasters_id' . $request->region_id,
        ],
        [
            'required' => 'This field is required'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'region_id' => 'required',
            'city_id' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('city_regionmappings', 'citymasters_id')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where('regionmasters_id', $request->region_id);
                })
            ]
    }
```